# What are the scripts to add for the support of kendo grid and chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a doubt about kendo UI .I using Kendo chart and grid when ever i add the dataviz js script to my page and when ever loading the page grid is not displaying any columns.That is I can add only web or dataviz. Here are the script i added Is there any inter dependency between chart and grid.

```
<link href="KENDO/js/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="KENDO/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.dataviz.stock.min.js"></script>
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="KENDO/js/console.js"></script>
```

Comment: "Here are the script i added"... you forgot it?

Comment: sorry I forgot..!<link href="KENDO/js/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="KENDO/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.dataviz.stock.min.js" ></script>
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="KENDO/js/console.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should add for styling KendoUI web:

```
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

This is what you need for running KendoUI web:

```
<script src="KENDO/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

This is for styling Kendo UI dataviz:

```
<link href="KENDO/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

And this is for running Kendo UI dataviz:

```
<script src="KENDO/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
```

The others are for demos (you don't need them)

Comment: Ok when ever i add dataviz.min.js the grid was showing empty without displaying any columns.

Comment: Which error do you get in the console of your browser? Could you show us some code in JSfiddle?